# Promise.allSettled is not a function with node 14.0.0

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to start an app which includes a simple `Promise.allSettled()`, but it crashes at start with the following error :

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Promise.allSettled is not a function
```

I looked it up, and most answers are related to allSettled not being available before node 12.9, but I'm running v14.0.0

How can I fix this ?

Comment: Are you using Typescript in your project?

Comment: @AlexZeDim no, just plain js

Comment: Well, as I remember, it's ES2020 feature, the only thing I could say here, just to check your config files for support of such syntax

Comment: what is the output of `node --version`? Just to make sure, you don't have something like `nvm` installed and it's pointing to a wrong version ...

Comment: @derpirscher I'm using nvm, but it's using node v14.0.0 (or at least, typing `node --version` and `nvm current` say so)

Comment: Also, my whole team is able to start the project, running the same npm and node versions, but I'm the only one using Ubuntu

Comment: Are you starting this from the console or from within some IDE? Might be a path issue and there may be an older version installed from the ubuntu repositories. And VS Code sometimes has troubles dealing with nvm. It really seems strange that something reporting as node v14 won't recognize Promise.allSettled()

Comment: @derpirscher I tried from both the console and the IDE, and running `console.log(process.client)` outputs 14.0.0. The best/worst part is that VSCode actually recognized Promise.allSettled as a function

Comment: This may sound dumb, but try deleting `Promise.allSettled(`, and typing (really type, don't C&P) it in again. There are numerous questions on stackoverflow, where (by whatever reason) similar looking but nonetheless wrong characters raised such or similar issues ...

Comment: And you can also try to just start the node REPL with `node` and typein `Promise.allSettled([])` in the prompt. What happens? You should not get an error

Comment: @derpirscher typing it again didn't solve the problem. Running it trhough the node console worked

Comment: How do you start your project? Directly with `node foo.js` or is there some `npm` script or whatever involved? Can you create a `foo.js` which just contains `Promise.allSettled([])` and start it via `node foo.js` If this works, it's not a problem of node but of your project/project configuation (maybe related to ubuntu?)

Comment: @derpirscher no, I'm starting it with the following : `lerna run start --scope=@components-wp/app --stream`

Comment: @derpirscher OK, i found a valuable clue: logging process.version inside my app outputs 11.0.0. The funny thing is that I don't have this version installed (when using nvm list, I see v12, v13 and v14, but no v11)

Comment: @PierreOlivierTran check if you have a version of node installed from the ubuntu repositores. Maybe that startup script fires up an additional shell which does not set the environments right ... You can also use `nvm deactivate` to temporarly deactive nvm's version of node and then check if there is an additional node executable in the path

Comment: And then, you'll have to fiddle out, what that startup script does to your environment

Comment: @derpirscher man you're my hero. Indeed, deactivating nvm showed me that I was using /usr/loca/bin/node, which was set to v11. I removed this version, re-activated nvm, recreated the symlink, and it worked !!